# Microsoft Excel - adding conditionally across sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

Summing multiple excel sheets conditionally based on criteria

I need some help please...

I have a table in SheetA with rows labled sheet1...sheetx in column A.  In column B, I have an "x" or blank beside each row.

In SheetA

```
Sheet1    x  
Sheet2       
Sheet3    x  
Sheet4    x  
Sheet5
```

etc...

I need to sum a cell (say B10) from each sheet identified with an "x".   So in my example, I need to add Sheet1!B10+Sheet3!B10+Sheet4!B10+...

I've been playing with Indirect to grab the reference sheet name from column A, but I cant figure out how to check column B for an "x", then add the same cell from only those sheets identified.

I've obviously simplified this a bit.

Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sheet names in A1:A5, markers (i.e. "x") in B1:B5 and text string representing choice of cell to be summed (e.g. "B10") in D1:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(B1:B5="x"),N(INDIRECT("'"&A1:A5&"'!"&D1)))`

Regards

Comment: This is good!  Getting closer....  how can I modify this so I dont have the hard coded reference in D1?   I want to place the formula in any cell, and have it pick up the same cell on all sheets.   Some combination of Row() and Column()?

Comment: What do you mean by "the same cell"? Relative to what? Perhaps clarify with an actual example.

Comment: I think I got it....this is what I'm looking for I think
=SUMPRODUCT(0+($B$1:$B$4="x"),N(INDIRECT("'"&$A$1:$A$4&"'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))))

Comment: It works when I have the formula on the same page as the sheet names and markers (called MasterSheet).   What doesnt seem to work is when I try the formula on a different page and substitute range references (ie. $A1:$A4) in the above formula with MasterSheet!$A1:$A4.   Any suggestions?

Comment: It works!   Thank you!  Final version of formula....

=SUMPRODUCT(0+(Groupings!$F$6:$F$43="x"),N(INDIRECT("'"&Groupings!$C$6:$C$43&"'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but one option would be to pull the values to the master sheet and sum them there. What I mean is, say your master sheet looks like this:

```
    A    B
1 Sheet1 x
2 Sheet2
3 Sheet3 x
```

In C1, put:

```
=IF(B1="x",INDIRECT(A1&"!B10"),"")
```

and fill down. That will pull the values into your master sheet, and you can sum those.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that wouldn't be feasible in my situation... I have 30+sheets formatted the same way...with large amounts of data in many rows/columns.   What I'm trying to achieve is a way to use the summary sheet to create a sum of a subset of the data sheets, in the same format (rows/columns)...and flexible enough to allow the data to be selected for summary using the master table.

Comment: @davex Yeah, I assume you want something like `=SUMIF($B:$B,"x",INDIRECT($A:$A&"!$B$10",0))` except, you know, working. :-) I tried to come up with something like that but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: I appreciate you trying. That's kinda exactly what I need..."create a summary page of all data in sheets identified by an x".   Never tried one of these boards, so I'm hoping there are tons of experts lurking in the shadows.    crossing my fingers..   the alternative is VERY manual